# SharePoint 2013 REST API: How can I clear a non-string field value?

Tags: 2013, rest, list-item, updatelistitems

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 REST API (my last choice, technological constraints require using it vs CSOM) and am encountering an issue when trying to clear any non-string (date, number, etc) field value.

Assume my list item has three columns, named CustomColumn1, CustomColumn2, and CustomColumn3. CustomColumn1 is a single-line string column, CustomColumn2 is a datetime column, and CustomColumn3 is a number column.

If I make a POST with the X-HTTP-METHOD set to "MERGE," meaning I want to update an existing list item, the following results occur:

**Scenario 1 Postdata**

```
{'__metadata': { 'type' : 'SP.Data.MYITEMTYPE' }, 'CustomColumn1' : 'string value', 'CustomColumn2' : '12/20/2013', 'CustomColumn3' : '123.45'}
```

**Scenario 1 Result**

Each field is updated properly.

---

**Scenario 2 Postdata**

```
"{'__metadata': { 'type' : 'SP.Data.MYITEMTYPE' }, 'CustomColumn1' : '', 'CustomColumn2' : '12/21/2013', 'CustomColumn3' : '123.456'}"
```

**Scenario 2 Result**

CustomColumn1 is cleared, CustomColumn2 and CustomColumn3 are updated.

---

**Scenario 3 Postdata**

```
"{'__metadata': { 'type' : 'SP.Data.MYITEMTYPE' }, 'CustomColumn1' : '', 'CustomColumn2' : '', 'CustomColumn3' : ''}"
```

**Scenario 3 Result**

SharePoint returns a 400 error, bad request.

---

**Scenario 4 Postdata**

```
"{'__metadata': { 'type' : 'SP.Data.MYITEMTYPE' }, 'CustomColumn1' : '', 'CustomColumn2' : NULL, 'CustomColumn3' : NULL}"
```

**Scenario 4 Result**

SharePoint returns a 400 error, bad request.

---

**Scenario 5 Postdata**

```
"{'__metadata': { 'type' : 'SP.Data.MYITEMTYPE' }, 'CustomColumn1' : '', 'CustomColumn2' : 'NULL', 'CustomColumn3' : 'NULL'}"
```

**Scenario 5 Result**

SharePoint returns a 400 error, bad request.

---

After spending a while researching, I did not find any kind of solution to this. I found a Microsoft document of "[SharePoint 2013 known issues](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/sharepoint-server-2013-known-issues-HA102919021.aspx)" that seems to outline this as a known issue, but the solution doesn't really line up with the problem.

Exact quote:

> Updating a list item doesn’t work when updating an item field with empty value
>
> When you try to update list item field that is non-string types, such as Date/Time, Boolean, Number, or Person, with empty value using Update List Item action, it doesn’t work. Updating string type field with empty string or updating single user type field with empty value works well.
>
> **Workaround**    Try to call the SharePoint 2010 workflow using the Start a list/site workflow action.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change NULL to null. I tried the following - first test resulted in a 400 Bad Request error, the second one worked fine.

```
{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },'StartDate': NULL}

{'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },'StartDate': null}
```